# Building URLs behind load balancer

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm building URLs using the following way:

```
String url = Url.Action(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString(),
                               ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString(),
                                                             new RouteValueDictionary()
                                                                 {
                                                                     {"x", "val"},
                                                                     {"y", "val2"
                                                                 },
                               Request.Url.Scheme
                                                             );
```

Resulting URL is like this: http://xyz.net:8081/abc/lang/controller/action

The environment is used behind a load balancer (uses also another port).

So the "http://xyz.net:8081/abc" part of the url should be changed (the part could be configured in web.config).

What would be the best way to solve this?

Comment: Let the load balancer worry about routing the request, externally, always use the same url.

Comment: You should only be generating the /abc/lang/controller/action portion so that the link will be relative to whatever site/port is accessing it. This is how you would do "sticky" sessions.

Comment: @QuetiMporta: That's exactly, what I want. But the way I do it like above, always a complete URL is generated...